# what is the correct way of getting user data from SharedPrefManager and setting it to viewbinding?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I get the user data from SharedPrefManager and set the values to viewbinding but when I tried to proceed to the next activity it stuck in progress dialog.

I tried to remove the code that gets user details:

```
User user = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getUser();

binding.nameBox.setText(user.getUsername());
binding.emailBox.setText(user.getEmail());
binding.phoneBox.setText(user.getPhone());
binding.addressBox.setText(user.getAddress());
```

But I need to get the user details so they will not enter it repeatedly. I am still no good in viewbinding but I still understand some part of it. I just couldn't understand why this (probably) simple thing of getting and setting user data can be difficult. Any help is greatly appreciated!

here is the code:

```
public class CheckoutActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityCheckoutBinding binding;
    CartAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<Product> products;
    double totalPrice = 0;
    final int tax = 0;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    Cart cart;
    String name;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityCheckoutBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        User user = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getUser();

        //setting the values to the textviews

        binding.nameBox.setText(user.getUsername());
        binding.emailBox.setText(user.getEmail());
        binding.phoneBox.setText(user.getPhone());
        binding.addressBox.setText(user.getAddress());

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Processing...");

        products = new ArrayList<>();

        cart = TinyCartHelper.getCart();

        for(Map.Entry<Item, Integer> item : cart.getAllItemsWithQty().entrySet()) {
            Product product = (Product) item.getKey();
            int quantity = item.getValue();
            product.setQuantity(quantity);

            products.add(product);
        }

        adapter = new CartAdapter(this, products, new CartAdapter.CartListener() {
            @Override
            public void onQuantityChanged() {
                binding.subtotal.setText(String.format("PHP %.2f",cart.getTotalPrice()));
                //binding.subtotal.setText(String.valueOf(cart.getTotalPrice()));
            }
        });

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        DividerItemDecoration itemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(this, layoutManager.getOrientation());
        binding.cartList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        binding.cartList.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);
        binding.cartList.setAdapter(adapter);

        binding.subtotal.setText(String.format("PHP %.2f",cart.getTotalPrice()));

        totalPrice = (cart.getTotalPrice().doubleValue() * tax / 100) + cart.getTotalPrice().doubleValue();
        binding.total.setText("PHP " + totalPrice);

        binding.checkoutBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                processOrder();
            }
        });

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    void processOrder() {
        progressDialog.show();
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        JSONObject productOrder = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject dataObject = new JSONObject();

        try {

            productOrder.put("address",binding.addressBox.getText().toString());
            productOrder.put("buyer",binding.nameBox.getText().toString());
            productOrder.put("comment", binding.commentBox.getText().toString());
            productOrder.put("created_at", Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
            productOrder.put("last_update", Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
            productOrder.put("date_ship", Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
            productOrder.put("email", binding.emailBox.getText().toString());
            productOrder.put("phone", binding.phoneBox.getText().toString());
            productOrder.put("serial", "cab8c1a4e4421a3b");
            productOrder.put("shipping", "");
            productOrder.put("shipping_location", "");
            productOrder.put("shipping_rate", "0.0");
            productOrder.put("status", "WAITING");
            productOrder.put("tax", tax);
            productOrder.put("total_fees", totalPrice);

            JSONArray product_order_detail = new JSONArray();
            for(Map.Entry<Item, Integer> item : cart.getAllItemsWithQty().entrySet()) {
                Product product = (Product) item.getKey();
                int quantity = item.getValue();
                product.setQuantity(quantity);

                JSONObject productObj = new JSONObject();
                productObj.put("amount", quantity);
                productObj.put("price_item", product.getPrice());
                productObj.put("product_id", product.getId());
                productObj.put("product_name", product.getName());
                product_order_detail.put(productObj);
            }

            dataObject.put("product_order",productOrder);
            dataObject.put("product_order_detail",product_order_detail);

            Log.e("err", dataObject.toString());

        } catch (JSONException e) {}

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.POST_ORDER_URL, dataObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    if (response.getString("status").equals("success")) {
                        Toast.makeText(CheckoutActivity.this, "Success order.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        String orderNumber = response.getJSONObject("data").getString("code");
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(CheckoutActivity.this)
                                .setTitle("Order Successful")
                                .setCancelable(false)
                                .setMessage("Your order number is: " + orderNumber)
                        .setPositiveButton("Pay Now", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(CheckoutActivity.this, PaymentActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("orderCode", orderNumber);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            }
                        }).show();
                    } else {
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(CheckoutActivity.this)
                                .setTitle("Order Failed")
                                .setMessage("Something went wrong, please try again.")
                                .setCancelable(false)
                                .setPositiveButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                                    }
                                }).show();
                        Toast.makeText(CheckoutActivity.this, "Failed order.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Log.e("res", response.toString());
                } catch (Exception e) {}
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                headers.put("Security","secure_code");
                return headers;
            }
        } ;

        queue.add(request);

    }
}
```